# How to remove the extra whitespace, if one of the print statement doesn't have a middle name?

Tags: python, function

```
def get_formatted_name(first_name, last_name, middle_name = ''):
    """Return a full name, neatly formatted."""
    if middle_name:
        full_name = f"{first_name} {middle_name} {last_name}"
    else:
        full_name = f"{first_name} {middle_name} {last_name}"
    return full_name.title()

cricketer = get_formatted_name('sachin', 'tendulkar')
print(cricketer)

cricketer = get_formatted_name('sachin', 'tendulkar', 'ramesh')
print(cricketer)
```

Output:

```
Sachin  Tendulkar
Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar
```

How to remove extra whitespace in first print output because there is no middle name?

Comment: Given that you *already* have a condition on whether or not there's a middle name, why do you still include it in the else case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include the middle name in the `else` statement

```
def get_formatted_name(first_name, last_name, middle_name = ''):
    """Return a full name, neatly formatted."""
    if middle_name:
        full_name = f"{first_name} {middle_name} {last_name}"
    else:
        full_name = f"{first_name} {last_name}"
    return full_name.title()

cricketer = get_formatted_name('sachin', 'tendulkar')
print(cricketer)

cricketer = get_formatted_name('sachin', 'tendulkar', 'ramesh')
print(cricketer)
```

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás Well, there are spaces, mate.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_formatted_name(first_name, last_name, middle_name = ''):
    """Return a full name, neatly formatted."""
    full_name = f"{first_name} {middle_name} {last_name}"
    return full_name.title()

cricketer = get_formatted_name('sachin', 'tendulkar')
print(cricketer.replace("  ", " "))
cricketer = get_formatted_name('sachin', 'tendulkar', 'ramesh')
print(cricketer.replace("  ", " "))
```

I had removed the `if .. else ..` condition check and in **print**  statement I just replaced 2 spaces with single space i.e, `print(cricketer.replace("  ", " "))` and if there is no space it doesn't effect.

**Output**

```
Sachin Tendulkar
Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar
```